# Kivy Two Buttons... How to make one of the Buttons remove the other on pressing it?

Tags: python, android, button, kivy

I have this code, there are two Buttons, "Normal Button" and "Remove Button" in a Screen. I need the Normal Button to be removed on pressing the "Remove Button"... Please help, need it for a imp project.

Main code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager

class Main(Screen):
    def remove(self):
        self.remove_widget(self.btn) # I'm not sure what to put here

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv=Builder.load_file("btn.kv")
screen=Manager()
screen.add_widget(Main(name="main"))

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen

Test().run()
```

KV code:

```
<Main>:
    name: "main"
    GridLayout:
        id: GL
        cols: 1
        size_hint: (.5,.5)
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
        Button:
            id: btn
            text: "Remove Button"
            size_hint: (.5,.5)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.6}
        Button:
            id: btn2
            text: "Normal Button"
            size_hint: (.5,.5)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.4}
            on_press:
                root.remove()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want the `Remove Button` to do the remove, then you must bind the `Remove Button` to the `remove()` method:

```
    Button:
        id: btn
        text: "Remove Button"
        size_hint: (.5,.5)
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.6}
        on_press:
            root.remove(btn2)
    Button:
        id: btn2
        text: "Normal Button"
        size_hint: (.5,.5)
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.4}
```

You can pass the `Button` to be removed to the `remove()` method by using the `btn2` `id` as an argument to the `remove()` method.

Then you can use that argument in the `remove()` method:

```
class Main(Screen):
    def remove(self, butt):
        gl = self.ids.GL
        if butt in gl.children:
            gl.remove_widget(butt)
        else:
            print('already removed')
```